# How can i do this look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text :

```
var obj = 
{
    text: 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.'
}
```

And i need put `new lines` on correct and points.

I try this:

```html
<script>
var obj = 
{
    text: 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.'
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj).split(/[^\sA-Z]\.(?=\s|[A-Z])/).join("."+"<br><br>"));

</script>
```

How can I put this new line without removing the last letter?

Comment: Show an example of what you would like the output to be, that will be easier to understand what you are looking to do.

Comment: Yeah show desired input and output

Comment: @Zinc im sorry i dont have a good english, but this party " i need put new lines on correct and points" dont say my desired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can use your pattern inside a simple `replace` method, just use a `$&<br><br>` replacement pattern:

```
your_string.replace(/[^\sA-Z]\.(?=\s|[A-Z])/g, '$&<br><br>')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsFMYb/1)

The `$&` backreference refers to the *whole match* value, what has been consumed with the `[^\sA-Z]\.` subpattern (any char other than whitespace and uppercase ASCII letters and a dot).

Comment: Tks man works perfectly ! Sorry edit, i dont see `BC.` match , can help with this one ? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: `BC.` does not match because of `[^\sA-Z]` - there cannot be an uppercase before the `.`. Maybe you want to add allowed abbreviations? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsFMYb/3), `(?:\bBC|[^\sA-Z])\.(?=\s|[A-Z])`. (**Note** that there is a bug at regex101 now, namely `$&` backreference does not work for JS flavor testing, but it works well in all browsers in fact).

Comment: Perfect ! Tks a lot, May indicate some study reference regex ? Not more...tks